# Enable UTF-8 or set custom font with TheArtOfDev's HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp

Tags: html, pdf, html-renderer

I'm using **TheArtOfDev's HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp** to convert an HTML string to PDF in a ASP.NET web application. The HTML contains Japanese characters. The Japanese symbols are converted to ☐ ascii characters.

How can I enable UTF-8 or use a custom Japanese font? I tried the following without results:

- Adding `<head><meta charset='utf-8'></head>` to the HTML string.
- Adding `<style>@font-face { font-family: myFont;　src: url('path/font.ttf'); }</style>` to the HTML string and then settings the font style on the element with Japanese text.
- Try a CSS file with `@font-face` and calling `TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.ParseStyleSheet`

Comment: It may have not helped you with your Japanese Character Set but you just saved my ass with the addition to the Head.  I couldn't find the documentation on getting it to recognize script fonts.  Thank you

Comment: @Sicae I'm glad at least someone got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on HTMLRenderer and PDFSharp and solved all my issues with [TuesPechkin](https://github.com/tuespetre/TuesPechkin), a wrapper for *wkhtmltopdf*.

Comment: Can you explain how you use fonts with TuesPechkin? Are there online or on a local disk?

Comment: @sinsedrix
I ended up not doing anything manually with fonts. I pass my HTML to TuesPechkin and it just works.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not possible to include custom fonts in HTML with PdfSharp, you can use custom fonts with DrawString if you use [IFontResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726223/pdfsharp-migradoc-font-resolver-for-embedded-fonts-system-argumentexception) to add your .ttf files.

Instead of using HTML and CSS to create a page layout, I used XGraphics.MeasureString and XGraphics.DrawString to create my own layout with PdfSharp.  This avoids all of the problems with page breaks which I encountered with CSS.

```
var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
var size = gfx.MeasureString(text, pageFont);
gfx.DrawString(text, pageFont, XBrushes.Black,
   new XRect(x, y, width, height),
   XStringFormats.BottomCenter);
```

I used Microsoft.Toolkit.Parsers.Markdown to parse a markdown string which I rendered to a PDF with MeasureString and DrawString.  You may need to create a mechanism for adding line breaks and page breaks if you are not going to use HTML/CSS.